# Django: How to get proper numerical ordering for a slug field?

Tags: django-models, operator-precedence, meta, slug

The slug field definition and the ordering of the model is depicted below.

from models.py:

```
class Ayah(models.Model):
    suraya = models.SlugField(max_length=8,unique=True)

    class Meta:
    ordering = ['suraya']
```

However, there is an undesired result in the resulting order.

```
17-81-15    
17-82-15    
17-85-15    
2-186-2 
2-256-3
```

The desired ordering is the numerical order before the dash.
So 2-whatever should come in order before 17-whatever .

There is probably a simple way to accomplish this through, maybe, regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much data you have, the easiest solution would be to add another column with only the leading number as an `IntegerField()` and then use it for sorting.

```
class Ayah(models.Model):
    suraya = models.SlugField(max_length=8,unique=True)
    suraya_sort = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['suraya_sort']
```

Then overwrite the `save()` method to always store the first number to the sort column automatically.

Comment: thank you for that. Problem is I do have alot of data and I learned my lesson not to mess with a model with a populated database.  What I had in mind was overriding the ordering method within the Meta class.  I am not fluent in regular expressions, whıch is probably needed to accomplish this.

Comment: If you do have a lot of data, you don't want to do the ordering in Python, because you would need to load the table's entire content to sort it. So it must be done in SQL. A regex to extract the first number would be `"^\d+"`.